# How to set the window movement key?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys

In 11.04, I could go to "Windows" under "System Settings" to change the the key used to grab/move windows, which is by default <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

In 11.10, the "Window" option is no longer under "System Settings" and I can't find the movement key shortcut in the "Shortcuts" menu under "Keyboard". I don't know where else to check...

The reason I need to change that setting is to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key under Wine in Photoshop. Photoshop is the only Windows application I use (other than Rosetta Stone), so I'd like to have its full functionality under Wine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here: [How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button)

In resume: The Compiz Plugin, at 'Move Window', have this settings.