# How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

I have problem with this function because i work in Maya and other 3D applications that use this key combination... This option on Ubuntu 11.04 was in "window" section so i could change it to something else to avoid conflicts... where is this located in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: did any answer help you solve the maya issue? as Autodesk doesn't officially support Maya for Ubuntu, it'd be interesting to know, and if so, maybe mark which answer was helpful? cheers

Comment: how is a Soluton for Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 40):

It’s a Compiz plugin.

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` in a terminal) and open it.

Once opened, search for a “Move Window” plugin. Select it, and disable or change the first option, “Initiate Window Move”.

[image: CCSM window]

For Unity 2d:

- [How to disable alt+click from moving windows in Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80623/how-to-disable-altclick-from-moving-windows)

Comment: The original poster didn't specify what version of Unity he was using. Ubuntu users with computers that can't handle Compiz are running Unity-2D with Metacity. The solution you posted doesn't work for them. If possible, you should provide both solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I was having trouble with Sublime Text 3 and this helped :)

Comment: Disabling "Initiate window movement" option somehow doesn't work for me. Any ideas how I can force compiz to disable it?

Comment: not sure if it worked for the maya issue (i'm guessing it did) but it did solve it for me (regarding sublime and atom editors) much appreciated, Fitoschido. Also, I recommend Samuel's method even better.

Comment: @disfated disabling also didn't work for me. I had to disable the plugin completely OR set it to something else. I selected all modifier keys + button 20. Hopefully it will never get in the way again!

Comment: CompizConfig Settings Manager can be started with `ccsm`, in case anybody wonders.

Comment: For me, the settings in CompizConfig had no effect at all, but the answer by @exponity-w works.

Answer (score 24):

With regard to Fitoschido's answer:

Clicking on the `<Alt>Button1` and just **disabling it** didn't work for me - it had no effect (and when restarting the computer, is was enabled again!). (I'm on Ubuntu 13.10)

What worked was clicking on the `<Alt>Button1` and setting it to a different combination, for example ALT-**SUPER** button1.

Comment: Also note that setting it to Alt+<Some other key> doesn't seem to work. You **must** add another option button like `super`

Answer (score 6):

This worked fine for me on Ubuntu 15.10 (command in terminal):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier '"<SUPER>"'
```

This changes Mouse+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination to Mouse+<kbd>Super</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you very much! This command works like a charm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

In **conf-editor** (you can open it from terminal) go to:
**/apps/metacity/general**
In the "**mouse_button_modifier**" option change `<Alt>` to `<Super>` or something else.

Comment: This does not work for Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @Crimbo the conf-editor route is for older versions, the Compiz route is for newer versions like yours.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Eagle CAD, and I learned from another forum that you can hold the `Super` key (windows key for me) before pressing `Alt`.