# How to disable alt+click from moving windows in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-2d, window-manager

How can I disable the alt+click combination from moving windows in Ubuntu 11.10 (unity-2d)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Unity-2D, this is controlled using the `/apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier` GConf key. To disable Alt+Click dragging, run

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier --type string disabled
```

To re-enable it, run

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier --type string '<Alt>'
```

Note that this GConf key controls several mouse shortcuts:

- Alt+Click: Move windows
- Alt+Middle Click: Resize windows
- Alt+Right Click: Open a generic window menu

N.B: Disabling the modifier in this way can lead to the Alt+Drag behavior when no modifier keys are pressed (Every drag behaves like Alt+drag)
Setting the modifier to '<SUPER>' makes the Super/Windows key the modifier. Alt+Drag can then be used by applications, and Super+Drag to move the window.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier --type string '<SUPER>'
```

for Unity 3D

- [How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button)

Comment: Note: If you're like me, you thought this applies to the "Gnome-classic (no effects)" session as well (since it uses metacity too). But no. Even though it uses metacity, you need to disable it in compiz as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button). Then it's disabled both in **"Gnome-classic"** (Compiz) and **"Gnome-classic (no effects)** (metacity) sessions.