# How do I disable window move with alt + left mouse button in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, window-manager, window-management

There are [lots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80623/how-to-disable-altclick-from-moving-windows) of [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button) on this about Unity, **this is about GNOME shell**.

As with other posters, I use apps (Inkscape in particular) that uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>-Click and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-drag. GNOME shell is grabbing this off me and thus disabling features in the application.

I have tried

- using ccsm's Move plugin - you can turn this off and you still get Alt-drag window moving.
- using gconf editor to change `/apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier` - this has no effect AFAICS.

It's really hindering me. Otherwise I find GNOME shell a really productive environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button)

Comment: I would point out that it's not GNOME doing this, but rather Ubuntu.  The default for GNOME Shell is to have `<Super>` be the window modifier key.

Comment: @DanielQuinn Indeed. Filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1704580 to ask Ubuntu to switch it back to Super/Windows key.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

First of all, install [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools].

To do that, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then open it, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> → `dconf-editor`.

Scroll down to `org` → `gnome` → `desktop` → `wm` → `preferences` → `mouse-button-modifier` → Set it to whichever key you like.

[image]

---

Or, equivalently,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```

in the terminal. (This requires neither `dconf-editor`, nor [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools])

**Warning:** Setting it to nothing means that all clicks move windows, instead of disabling it!

Comment: Warning! Setting it to nothing means that *all* clicks move windows, instead of disabling it!

Comment: This setting seems to reset for me each time I restart. Anyone know why? I suppose I could just add the command line to my Startup applications however.

Comment: I tried the dconf-editor method, but nothing seems to have happened. <ALT> is still my modifier key. I have tried "['<Control><Alt>']" (following the syntax of the keybindings options) and "<Control><Alt>". Do I need to restart in order for this to take effect?

Comment: I first tried it with the `gsettings` command, and it seems to have changed it successfully, but Alt+Drag would still move the window. Even after a restart. I then installed *dconf-tools* and confirmed with the *dconf-editor* that `mouse-button-modifier` indeed **was** changed, but as I said, Alt+Drag still moves windows. (I'm on Mint Cinnamon 17.2 64bit)

Comment: "<Alt>+<Super>" value pretty works for me

Comment: FYI: On Mint 14.04.2 LTS I had to also do @swansong 's answer before it worked

Comment: Note that the `dconf-editor` entries is not sort by name, so you might need to search `mouse-button-modifier` in case you can't see  `desktop`.

Comment: On CentOS, I had to `sudo yum install dcond-editor` (there is no `dconf-tools` package.)

Comment: @Bloke: I think for **Cinnamon**, it should be `org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences` instead. At least that's what worked for me.

Comment: In **Cinnamon** you can just change it in the settings `Windows` > `Behaviour` > `Special key to move and resize windows`.

Comment: In Mate Desktop and 18.04.1LTS use this: `/org/mate/marco/general/mouse-button-modifier`. It works with Ctrl-drag (Control+Left Mouse drag) to move a window. Log out and back in and voila.

Comment: <Alt><Super> works in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 16):

In Mint(or Cinnamon) the key can be changed or disabled under

`system settings` > `windows` > `behavior` > `'Special key to move and resize window'`

I have it set to the super/windows key instead.

Comment: Thanks! The same goes for Cinnamon installed on other systems like Debian (my use case).

Comment: This works for Mate 18.04 through `Control Centre` > `Look and Feel` > `Windows` > `Behaviour` > `Movement Key`

Answer (score 11):

Use the Tweak Tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`):

Windows > Window Action Key

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me when everything using dconf-editor or the command line or compiz failed. Now I can use alt for other shortcuts and restore functionality to several programs.

Answer (score 9):

To resolve the Alt+Click move window dragging problem:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --set /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier --type string '<Super>'
```

Does the same thing, really, just with a different config tool, and less hunt-and-click.

For newer versions using dconf/gsettings, use this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"` for `dconf`.

Answer (score 7):

I set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> like a temporary solution. So I can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in Inkscape and <kbd>Super</kbd> for activities.

Comment: what do you mean by "activities"? I have changed `Alt` to `Super` and it works fine for me. I did not notice any side effects. Why would you need `Alt + Super`?

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Tour#Activities_Overview

If you set "Super" for moving windows you can't use it for show "Activities Overview". Look at posting time, it was two years ago.

Comment: Two years is nothing.

Answer (score 6):

In UBUNTU 14.04 LTS use in dconf syntax like

```
<Alt><Super>
```

Works well for me.

BTW: If you set something wrong, it starts to move window on every click.
Use  to navigate to "Set to Default" button. And hit .

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to System Settings
2. Select Keyboard
3. On the bottom left click on ‘Layout Settings’
4. Select your language and click the ‘Options’ button on the lower right
5. Select ‘Alt/Win key behavior’
6. Change it to the one you like. I use ‘Left Alt is swapped with Left Win’.