# How can I turn off alt-right mouse button function in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, window, blender

By default the <kbd>alt</kbd> + mouse combination activates the window menu.

The *activate the window menu* shortcut is currently set to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>-RMB key combo is used in blender for selecting edge loops.

Answer (score 3):

Install the compizconfig-settings-manager package and run ccsm. At `General | General Options | Key bindings | Window Menu` click on `Alt<Button3>`, de-select `Enabled` and click `OK`.

P.S. If this doesn't work, assign a different key to `Window Menu`. Thanks to Morichalion.

Comment: Doesn't work as written.

When I switch tabs or windows, it resets the keybinding.

I set it to another key, and that made the setting stick.

Answer (score 3):

Fix Alt-drag window move:

---

With Unity-2D (and now Gnome 3), this is controlled using the
`/apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier` GConf key. To disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> dragging, run:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier --type string '<Super>'
```

To re-enable it, run:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier --type string '<Alt>'
```

Note that this GConf key controls several mouse shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>: Move windows
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Click</kbd>: Resize windows
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>: Open a generic window menu

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-drag fix for gnome 3:
Here is the new fix:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --set /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier --type string '<Super>'
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

1. install `dconf-tools`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Then run:

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
3. Then navigate to:

   ```
   org → gnome → desktop → wm → preferences → mouse-button-modifier
   ```
4. Change the value to:

   `<Super>`
5. Close the `dconf-editor` window.

Why this should be necessary when there's a dialogue for system hotkeys under keyboard preferences, is beyond me. Very frustrating having to hunt it down with each new release/update of gnome!

Source: [How do I disable window move with alt + left mouse button in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118151/disable-alt-for-window-move-in-gnome-shell)

Comment: I set the value as "<Alt>+<Super>" so I can use 'Alt' in Inkscape and 'Super' for activities

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + RMB. That was the best solution I could find. You can customize your keys in Blender's user preferences to change loop selection to something else too.