# Installing Maya on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: installation, proprietary, alien

Installing Autodesk Maya on Ubuntu is possible, but can be a bit challenging.

Assuming that one already has the required specs and a solid graphics card driver installed, how can it be done?

Answer (score 7):

## Getting the Installer

First you need to download the actual linux rpm files from the autodesk website. Forget trying to bootleg it, Autodesk offers the files here: http://usa.autodesk.com/support/

## Getting a License

You should obtain a personal edition license, a student license, or a commercial license. Autodesk also includes the utilities needed to connect to a network license.

You can also rent a license (such as the Maya LE for only $50 a month).

Note that when going through the student license process, you won't be offered a Linux download. Simply prepare to download the Windows version, and you will be given and emailed a key that works with the linux version.

## Installing

Basically consists of converting the `.rpm` files to `.deb` files, installing the files, obtaining the proper libraries through `apt-get` and symlinking some files to make Maya happy.

See this script for the basic process: https://gist.github.com/MichaelLawton/32ca5cf6145f0ca4a7ebcdc510d7447d

## Some Problems & Solutions

#### How to disable Alt+Click drag (Note you can use Super also in Maya, but if you are used to alt like me this helps a lot):

[How do I disable window move with alt + left mouse button in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118151/how-do-i-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button-in-gnome-shell)

Fluxbox:
https://askubuntu.com/a/392752/226792

#### Ubuntu Linux Maya doesn't load at all. Running `maya` at the command prompt displays no output. Maya no gui, Maya hangs at startup, etc.

Try first running it as a super user `sudo maya`. You should be able to run it as a normal user afterwards.

If you get an error about `csh`, you need to `apt-get install csh` first.

You might also try removing your maya directory `~/maya` [[source]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020648&p=12199954#post12199954)

#### Ubuntu Linux Maya crashes when loading a file, Maya crashes when rendering. Maya some 3D elements missing, Maya grey starup screen, Maya crashes when making a file, etc.

1. You need `libjpeg62`
2. Remove the symlink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` [[Source]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020648&p=12795706#post12795706)

#### Maya does not load Mental Ray, `MENTALRAY_DIR` not a file

Install the mentalrayForMaya.rpm package with scripts:

```
fakeroot alien --scripts mentalrayForMaya.rpm && sudo dpkg -i mentalrayForMaya.deb
```

Comment: NB any [free] student licensees - [Linux is only supported for commercial](https://twitter.com/AutodeskHelp/status/477182657386651648) :-(

Comment: I'm about 2 years late on this post, but I ran the linked script and got output `/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. It failed. Any advice?

Comment: If you google the second half of your error message there's a few people with similar problems, for example: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885911 The general solution is to try to make sure the right libraries are installed and then symlink the libraries to wherever maya expects to find them.

Comment: thanks! does this process handle minor (patch) upgrades? how much needs to change when a new (major) version of maya comes out?

Comment: This might need some changes, it's been 2 years since I wrote the answer

Comment: That gist has 404 error now.

Comment: external github link is not working.

Comment: @SalihKaragoz I replaced the link with another just now