# Photoshop path not working properly under Wine

Tags: 12.04, wine, gimp, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button)

Great Community. I have a BIG question. I've installed Adobe Photoshop CS. I know that this version is old :(.

Well my problem is when I'm trying to use the path tool. I can make a new anchor point, but when i like to cut the point to make another (ALt + Click). It doesn't works. When I press the Alt button the window moves and I can't solve this problem by myself. Please help me!

P.D: I tried using GIMP. It's great :) but doesn't support CMYK color profile. That's the reason I used Photoshop under WINE.

Comment: You can also check [How to disable alt+click from moving windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/80623/65926)

Comment: **Thx bro it's solved**