# ubuntu-mate No luck disabling option-alt LEFT RIGHT mouse clicks

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-mate

Have tried several solutions for other flavors
[How to disable window move with alt + left mouse button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67518/how-to-disable-window-move-with-alt-left-mouse-button)
[How to disable alt+click from moving windows in Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80623/how-to-disable-altclick-from-moving-windows-in-unity-2d)

but no luck so far.
Any ubuntu-mate users no how to disable alt-option LEFT & RIGHT Mouse button clicks? They interfere with most 3D apps. I don't want option LEFT click to drag my entire IDE window, or option RIGHT click to resize my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I read this as "disable" as to "completely remove the functionality of" which was the case I had because it was conflicting with VSCode and Terminator's alt+click functionalities. In order to do that, open up dconf. If you don't have it you can get is using

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor -y
```

After that open dconf and navigate to org → mate → Marco → general → mouse-button-modifier. There change the switch to not use the default and remove 'Alt' from the text area leaving an empty text box.
[image: dconf org.mate.Marco.general.mouse-button-modifier]
Afterward, you will be able to use the functionalities of other programs with alt+click, but you will no longer be able to move a window with anything other than it's title bar.

Answer (score 0):

System -> Preferences -> Look and Feel -> Windows -> Behavior -> Movement Key

Change from Alt to Super.

BR
GAS

Comment: Please enrich your answers with screen shots.